# Bind second ip to specific port

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2012

Im using **Windows Server 2012** with **Two puplic ips**.
Need to set that a **specific port connects with second ip**.

The reason for this is that im runnig a application that connects to internet through a UDP port(I can define the port number). So I want to run two versions of that (each connects to different port) and have a uniqe ip for each one.

How can i achive this?

Comment: you have to think of it as the other way around. not ports but ips. you application must is binded to ip/port you need to look in the configuration for an option that allows you to bind it to two different ips.

Comment: @BANJOSA But it doesnt give me the option to choose ip. I can only set the port number for it

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do can be accomplished by tossing the programs into a Hyper-V VM. Starting at a Standard 2012 server key, it allows 2 VMs to be installed with that same key (a plethora of other options exist as well). You can bind each VM to a different Public IP. The VM only knowing it's singular public IP will force each instance of the program to go out the appropriate port and bind the the appropriate public IP.

**Installing Hyper V and setting up VM:** https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/hh846766(v%3Dws.11)

**Settings**

***HYPER-V***
- An External Virtaul Network - NO "Allow management operating systemto share this newtork adapter" / "Enable virtual LAN identification for management operating system"

***SCVMM***
 - Under "Networking" tab for the Host properties, Network bindings are set to "Physical network adapter."  NO "Host access"

***NIC settings***:

- Host's physical NIC in "Network Connections" will act as the Virtual Switch, showing "Microsoft Virtual Network Switch Protocol" enabled
  and everything else is disabled.
- Vm's virtual NIC in "Network Connections" is configured with a public IP and the default gateway set to the router as was
  originally.

Comment: Thanks. But with this solution i get two drawbacks: 
1- I want to have files accessible between two versions of application so they can read the same file.
2- Isnt VM affecting the overall performance of the server? i guess its gonna use unnecessary resources

Comment: @Cart.AT Ram utilized per VM is 512m to 1g each for the OS,  Can save on this by slimming it down post installation.  CPU utilization overhead by the OS should be rather low as well.  While yes it will use more resources than nothing, it gives you the benefit of 2 entirely isolated environments exposed to the nasty public web further separated from the host OS.  Also, Snapshots are awesome for if something implodes or if you want to add more programs to utilize your public IP.  If it breaks, roll it back. Host OS fully unaffected.

Comment: @Cart.AT Almost forgot your other point:  Set up a share drive/network drive from the host OS, the 2 VMs can then map that network drive as a native drive and read/write as normal.